Android project with Multiple Modules with ProductFlavours in 2 modules

I my project i have multiple modules, like ModuleA, ModuleB, ModuleC, ModuleD, ModuleE, ModuleF

I have different Flavours in ModuleA like( sit, prod, prepord),

same in moduleB have different flavors like ( RED, GREEN, BLUE, YELLOW, etc...)

and ModuleB will use all modules properties of (ModuleA, ModuleC, ModuleD, ModuleE, ModuleF)

ModuleC use Properties of (Module A),

ModuleD use Properties of (Module A),

ModuleE use Properties of (Module A),

Module F use Properties of (Module A)


here ModuleA is commonModule for (ModuleB,C,D,E,F)

HERE i need too change BaseURLS base on the flavour selection in ModuleA (if i select "sit" siturl should set, if i select "prod" prodUrl should set like this)

is it possible to select one flavour like(sit or prod or prepod any one of flavor) in ModuleA and same can i select any one if flavor in ModuleB like ( RED or any other).


how to do please explain with sample
when i try like selecting one flavor (sit) in ModuleA and one flavor (RED) in ModuleB, and when i trying to use the properties of ModuleA in ModuleB getting issues, project is not building.

i given ModuleA module path in ModuleB dependency.


Do you want sitRedDebug, prodGreenRelease something like this or only sit or only red to be main flour. What is the output flavor required

Concise:
 You must ensure the modules have the same flavor names to get compiled.
Explanation:
TO compile the project successfully you must ensure that each module has the same name of build variant out of your list like this:

Production
QA

Use case: Select QA product flavor across each module and your QA base URL from the build config file will get there.
